# PIC 12F508 Logic Level Calculations

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I am using a PIC 12F508 for a project and just want to make sure I understand the specifications in the datasheet for a logic low and a logic high.

[Here's the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41236E.pdf) for reference.  The specs I'm using are on page 73.

The pin in question is the MCLR pin which I have set in the configuration bits as an input so it's not functioning as a reset for the micro controller.

For a logic low it says 0.15 VDD I take it that means it's a percentage of the micro controllers supply voltage (VDD) right?

So say my VDD is 3.50V so 3.50 * 0.15 = 525 millivolts. So as long as the input remains below 525 millivolts the PIC will read it as a logic low?

I take it the same would apply to a logic high 3.50 * 0.85 = 2.975V or above would be read as a logic high right?

Comment: Note that those voltage levels only apply to Schmitt Trigger inputs. When the MCLR pin is assigned to GP3 it has standard TTL levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct on both counts. The default mathematical operation in an equation when none is given is multiplication.